# c++ open file in one line

Tags: c++, fstream

I've got these two lines of code

```
ifstream inputFile;
inputFile.open("data.txt");
```

I vaguely remember there being a way to do something similiar using one line of code instead. 
How to do it in one line?

Comment: to be more specific, how to say
`ifsteam myFile Filename`
I undertand that there may not be an option to open it too in the same line of code.

Comment: You can give the path directly to the constructor.

Comment: kudos for coding by remembering, I usually have to consult some documentation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the constructor to specify the filename:

`ifstream inputFile("data.txt");`

See the details for [`std::basic_ifstream (constructor)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream).

> explicit basic_ifstream( const char* filename,
>                   std::ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in );

---

> First, performs the same steps as the default constructor, then associates the stream with a file by calling rdbuf()->open(filename, mode | std::ios_base::in) (see std::basic_filebuf::open for the details on the effects of that call). If the open() call returns a null pointer, sets setstate(failbit)